# como usar API EnvioClick

Tags: php, api

No tengo tanta experiencia en POO con PHP, por lo que necesito de su ayuda, necesito consumir un API de una empresa de paquetería llamada envioclick (api.envioclickpro.com) La cosa es que realmente no tengo ni la mínima idea sobre como proceder por lo que les agradecería si me pudieran proporcionar orientación sobre el uso de APIS.

La documentación de la empresa no ayuda mucho que digamos.

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia. Acota el problema, dinos con qué estás empezando y qué dificultades tienes. Por pobre que sea la documentación algo explicarán ¿no? Al menos dirán como dirigir una petición a la API. Al menos tendrás un código que manda una petición ¿no? En base a eso entonces podrás preguntar sobre algo concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar peticiones a API externas desde PHP es necesario tener instalador la libreria cULR , debes tener ademas un poco de conocimientos sobre los que es JSON.

Agrego un ejemplo de como realizar la petición usando recursos tomados de https://www.codexworld.com/post-receive-json-data-using-php-curl/ y de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers/8115709

## Ejemplo petición API desde PHP.

```php
<?php
// abrimos la sesión cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// defino un PAQUETE A ENVIAR. 
//según https://api.envioclickpro.com/#/definitions/Package 
// un objeto paquete es asi:
 $el_paquete = [
  "description"=> "Pink iPad",
  "contentValue"=> 120.01,
  "weight"=> 1.01,
  "length"=> 30.01,
  "height"=> 15.01,
  "width"=> 20.01
 ];

 // ahora el ZIP_CODE de Oringe y Destino
 // según https://api.envioclickpro.com/#/definitions/QuotationRequest
 // se vera así.
 $el_origen = "44100";
 $el_destino = "44510";

// definimos la URL a la que hacemos la petición
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.envioclickpro.com/api/v1");

// Super importante la CLAVE DE API o api_key
// la encuentras en https://www.envioclickpro.com.co/account#apikey
// ser vera asi: 472fbd42-9450-4aba-bd56-e686bda33a09 crea la tuya propia.
$api_key = "472fbd42-9450-4aba-bd56-e686bda33a09";

// indicamos parametros de cabecera, tipo de petición y clave api
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                     'Content-Type:application/json',
                                     'api_key'.$api_key ));
// definimos cada uno de los parámetros de la consulta
curl_setopt($ch, 
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            json_encode( array("package"=> $el_paquete,
                          "origin_zip_code"=> $el_origen,
                          "destination_zip_code"=>$el_destino)
            );
 
// recibimos la respuesta y la guardamos en una variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$remote_server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 
// cerramos la sesión cURL
curl_close ($ch);
 
// hacemos lo que queramos con los datos recibidos
// por ejemplo, los mostramos
dd($remote_server_output);
?>
```

Comment: Trate con un codigo propio y logro conectarme al API, pero al momento de mandar el array codificado JSON me manda un error 400.

Comment: Buen, ya revise el código con la yuda del que escribio Diego Mesa y ha quedado funcionando, al parecer estaba inlcuyendo una linea en la cabecera que ocasionaba que todo se crasheara.

Comment: Si @NatNajera existia problea al declara `$api_key` faltaba punto y coma (he corregido el codigo ), si existe otra problema agradezco comentarlo tambien.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.